# Assign variable to url failed (JavaScript DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, background-image

Why does URL does not accept variable values like this
  let pic = 'img_tree.png';
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(pic)";

but accept "pic" variable value like this.
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+pic+"')";

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background image</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 let pic = 'img_tree.png';
   // document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(pic)"; ERROR
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+pic+"')"; // working fine
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when it's *inside* the quotes, it's just the letters "p", "i", and "c". But when it's *outside* the quotes, it's an identifier which is used to look up a value.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(pic)";
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−− string, the letters inside
//                                                     have no special meaning to
//                                                     JavaScript
```

vs.

```
//                                              vvv−−−−−−−−−−− identifier
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + pic + "')";
//                                    ^^^^^^^         ^^^^−−−− strings
```